# How does react-native-device-info Package work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, package, native-base

I have implemented `react-native-device-info` package in my React Native App & My University professor is now asking me to describe how does this package work in order to get the required info. what callbacks, etc are used or **how does it communicate with the system** to bring that info to us.

I have searched through the internet but can't seem to find the answer.

So, I want to know & learn how react-native packages work & more specifically the package `react-native-device-info` works?

Answer (score 1):

I went on to look at the source code for the package, and you will see that there are `ios` and `android` files in the root, and if you take a closer look you will see platform native code that is passing messages via the RN Bridge module. I am no expert on the field, but this should be the general explanation.